# Do I need Windows 8 to try Windows 8.1 Preview?

Tags: windows-8, dvd, windows-8.1-preview

When I try to boot a DFI LanParty-UT CFX3200 from a Windows 8.1 Preview DVD without having Windows 8 installed I get a `DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER` message.
Do I need Windows 8 to install Windows 8.1 Preview?

Comment: No.  Your inability to boot to the disk is because the disk isn't a bootable disk.  I don't know what you used to create it but thats likely the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not.

I'm unaware of any upgrade options for the Windows 8.1 Preview, but even if there are upgrade options you should be able to boot from the disk (in previous upgrades this was the case).

There's likely a problem the image you've downloaded, with the DVD you've burned, or your boot options. Ensure you've selected your DVD drive (I'm assuming you burned a DVD) as the primary boot option, or selected it as the temporary boot options. Failing that, burn another DVD. If you still can't get it to work, download the ISO again.

Might not hurt to pick through the manual on your motherboard either.

Comment: I'll try get a new DVD-reader. I don't even know if the old one supports DVDs.